# ¿ Cómo quitar totalmente la "status bar" y modificarla?

Tags: java, android, listview, bottombar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un tipo `Fragment`, donde tengo implentado un `ListView` con ciertos personajes. Resulta que tenia la típica barra azul de arriba con el nombre de la App y mediante el `manifest` la he quitado pero no puedo aprovechar el espacio de ésta, es decir, el `ListView` no llega hasta arriba, solo hasta el principio de la supuesta barra superior, y me quita mucho espacio.

**¿ Es posible desactivarla totalmente para poder aprovechar toda la pantalla?**

Otra cosa que podéis ver es el `BottomBar` de bajo, de color rojo, al estar los botones típicos de Android, empieza más arriba, **¿hay alguna forma de bajarlo o adaptarlo a los botones todavía mas ?**

ACTUALIZADO:

activity_main.xml

`< LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

`android:layout_width="match_parent"`

`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

`android:orientation="vertical"`

`android:layout_height="match_parent">`

```
<FrameLayout

    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: No entiendo que quieres hacer con los botones de abajo.

Comment: Quiero reducir el espacio que hay entre el límite de arriba de los botones de android y el límite inferior de los botones de mi app.

Comment: Es decir, que estén más próximos, bajarlos.

Comment: Pero es difícil, porque es un bottomBar...

Comment: @Error404 Respecto a la barra de arriba, lo que pido no es posible? He encontrado muchas páginas donde dicen cómo quitarla, eso sí, y después pasan capturas de pantalla sin ella, pero a la hora de hacer ListView.. se nota.

Comment: Como veo que ya te han respondido a la primera pregunta, yo te voy a responder aquí a la otra (no la pongo como respuesta ya que no estaría completa del todo, me faltaría la primera parte): Indagando en la documentación del bottombar(nunca lo había utilizado) he visto este apartado: https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar#user-content-how-do-i-draw-it-under-the-navbar. En esta sección vete al apartado "activity_my_awesome.xml". Creo que ahí se refiere a la bottombar inferior (no la de los iconos). Le cambias la height y listo ^^

Comment: Voy a echarle vistazo, supongo que ya habré mirado ese link, pero la miro m´sa profundamente y te digo,a  ver, porque llevo ya con esto del bottom bar... jajaja Gracias, por cierto ;)

Comment: Eso es ERROR de xml nada mas, tranquilamente puedes usar ese espacio..

Comment: En el XML está situado arriba del todo. Tanto la foto, como el listView, marlon.

Comment: @RfMvs en tu actividad estás seguro que no incluyes el toolbar ?..héchale un ojo a tu XML

Comment: @RfMvs te refieres a la barra de estatus donde se agregan las notificaciones???

Comment: Con imagen entiendo que quieres estás en problemas con el espacio del toolbar.. entonces también quieres ocupar la parte de arriba ?

Comment: Si seguro marlon, de todas formas no importa, lo dejo de momento de color negro que favorece a mi aplicación y si me da mas problemas volvere a este hilo o a otro nuevo.

Comment: Por cierto, Elena y marlon, si la quiero mantener y os digo que quiero un icono ahí en medio, sabeis como? Porque tengo el texto y pone el nombre de la aplicacion y no quiero tener el nombre de la aplicacion ahi arriba, si no un iconito, he intentado ponerlo pero no ha habido manera.

Comment: vale, esperad , que creo que se como, pero no estoy seguro, ahora actualizo.

Comment: jajaja crea un layout Relativo agregas un Toolbar y un ImageView; y nada mas juegas seteando el ImageView

Comment: Espera porque desde el manifest le he puesto android:icon así como el texto que me sale lo he quitado y a ver si funciona, jaja que cuento menos cosas cree mejor xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta colocar antes del `setContenView`:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Esto te pondrá en pantalla completa y ocupar toda tu pantalla, eso incluye ocultar los controles de navegación de **Android**. En caso de no funcionar, agrega otra *Flag* con `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION`

Aquí te muestro otra forma:

```
if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT )
        {
            getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility( View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION 
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN 
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY );
        }
```

Comment: Es un Fragment, no una activity, influye?

Comment: entonces lo tendras que hacer con la Activity que contenga el fragment

Comment: solo cambia que tengo que hacer getActivity().getWindow()..... a ver qué tal.

Comment: Editada la respuesta.

Comment: @x4mp73r He puesto eso en el Fragment y funciona, quita controles de navegación de **Android** pero la barra de BottomBar es la misma, no cambia, como si estuviera ahí todavia la barra, supongo que no se podrá no sé, si quereis paso foto de como me queda ahora si eso ayuda, no sé , decidme, por cierto, en la barra de arriba sigue sin dejarme aprovechar el espacio.

Comment: @RfMvs ¿Cuál de mis propuestas usaste?

Comment: La última con todas las FLAG , porque la primera no me funciona.

Answer (score 0):

> ¿ Cómo quitar totalmente la “default” bar de arriba y modificarla?

Me imagino te refieres a la **barra de estatus**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eliminarla y que veas algo similar a:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes realizarlo de esta forma:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide the status bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
// Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
// status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Para android 4.0 y anteriores puedes definir un theme sin "ActionBar" en tu Activity:

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
    ...
</application>
```

Si usas soporte con `AppCompat` :

```
   <application
        ...
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        ...
    </application>
```

Revisa la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html) acerca de tu pregunta.

Comment: Elena, es un Fragment, getActionBar() me da error. No va tampoco añadiendole getActivity().

Comment: oh depende del sistema operativo creo que tienes que validar con : if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT ..........) y usar: getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView() para acceder a la Actividad que contiene tu fragmento.

Comment: Elena, eso es lo que ha comentado **x4mp73r** y no me ha funcionado, es decir, se me ha puesto en pantalla completa, se me han quitado los comandos de android de serie pero el ``bottomBar `` seguía estando igual, con el mismo rojo.

Comment: Si entonces no puedo hacer nada respecto a eso... ¿ es posible al menos poner de negro la parte de los botones de android ? Para que no se vea tanto rojo

Comment: Pensé que lo habias solucionado tienes marcada esa respuesta como correcta... Lo que deseas eliminar es lo que indicas en tu imagen de color rojo?

Comment: Son 2 preguntas en una. Lo que yo quiero es que la barra de arriba que no se ve porque la he quitado, se pueda aprovechar, porque como ves la imagen no llega arriba y no es por culpa del xml, no hay nada que le moleste, simplemente esta invisible y ya está. Y la otra creo que es imposible porque si el movil android tiene ahí los botones poco se puede hacer..

Comment: puedes abrir chat para comentarte una cosa?

Answer (score -1):

Pienso que el error proviene del `XML` si te encuentras en un `Fragment` significa que vienes de un `Activity`.. entonces..
Tienes un `Layout` donde realizas esto

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:orientation="vertical">
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/> <!-- Toolbar incluído-->

    <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/contenedor_fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
 </LinearLayout>
<fragment../>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Entonces cada vez que haces un `replace` de `Fragment` por más código que tienes para solucionarlo no podrías ocupar el espacio de que sobra en la imagen, por qué definiste mal el XML..
en todo caso la acción que deberías tomar es asignar a cada `Fragment` un `Toolbar`, claro en todos los que necesites agregar

Entonces tendrías que quitarle el `Toolbar` y tu `Activity` se vería así

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/> -->

        <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/contenedor_fragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
     </LinearLayout>
    <fragment../>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Ya si quieres eliminar el `Toolbar` por default te tienes que ir a `styles.xml`
y agregar estas 2 líneas de código

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item> <!--eliminar titulo-->
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item> <!--eliminar toolbar-->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Sé lo que quieres decir, pero la unica activity que tengo es el main, y parto de un bottombar que son todo fragments. He revisado pero en ningun lado incluyo toolbar :S

Comment: Entonces necesitaría revisar tu XML

Comment: Me tengo que ir a un sitio, en cuanto vuelva mañana vuelvo aquí y actualizo. Lo que sí no entiendo, que con hacer lo de AppCompat.NoActionBar y tal en el manifest, si que se quitaba en el xml, veías como no aparecía y después en el móvil, no se veía pero no te dejaba poner nada, como si fuera invisible.. mañana actualizo con el xml del fragment y el de activity.

Comment: Eso es la perspectiva de tu Android Studio al ver los layouts para que entiendas.. recuerdas que desarrollar puedes ver el tipo de dispositivo, versión SDK, tema(el tuyo es AppCompat.NoActionBar, al parecer..)

Comment: atualizado marlon